# How do you headshot a Bastion in Sentry or Tank configuration?

Tags: overwatch

Can you headshot a Bastion in Sentry or Tank configuration?

I only found an old [reddit-discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/3dzyjq/does_bastion_have_a_head_while_transformed/) where this picture was posted:

[image: Bastion Head]

It seems to me that this might be the former head.
In Tank mode however it's getting even harder. I could not find a picture from all sides so I'm setteling with this one:

[image: Bastiontankmode]

The part right behind the gun would be my guess but I am unsure.
Also that the model appeared to have changed a lot since the early versions of the game make it hard to find accurate information.

So just to repeat myself: Can I shoot bastion in the head and if so, where do I shoot?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Configuration: Recon mode:

- His headshot hitbox is the entirety of his head. He has no vulnerabilities in the front or the back.

[image]

### Configuration: Sentry mode:

- His headshot hitbox is this cyan-colored box sticking out of his back. Shooting this deals the same damage as a headshot.

[image]

### Configuration: Tank mode:

- He has no headshot hitbox in Tank mode; in fact the opening that's exposed in Sentry mode is completely covered up in Tank mode

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Great News!
Bastion does in fact actually have a critical hit point (headshot) while he is in turret mode. On the back of the turret you will see a blue-like box, that is his weak spot that acts as a headshot point. So, to answer, yes, you can headshot Bastion in turret mode, though we don't think there is a Critical Hit Point on his Tank Form, thankfully though he can only stay in tank form for a short while. Hope this helped!

Comment: I had at one point thrown 6 shuricanes on that blue box as genji in meleerange. He still had like 15% life left. is Genjis shuricane damage that low, or is a headshot multiplyer just marginal?

Comment: @Zaibis *shuriken, and yes, they do very little damage unless you quickly throw out multiple alternate fires from close range. In fact, the weakpoint in sentry configuraton is even weaker than head weakpoints.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer; Ah ok, thats well to know and should be contained in one of the answers. Does the alternate fire deal more damage? I do even on closerange everytime primary fire, due to fearing that one shuriken could miss anyway.

Comment: @Zaibis The alternate fire fires three shurikens much faster than the primary fire, but each shuriken does the same damage. Therefore, the DPS is higher if you can hit all three.